# Is there a way to quit the current function based on a condition but not end the program

Tags: sql, python-3.x, exit

I have 2 class methods. One method 'accountExistance()' checks if an account already exists by finding a duplicate username in a database and the other method 'customerDetails()' writes the user registration details to the database. My customerDetails() method calls the 'accountExistance() method and if there is a duplicate username, which is checked within 'accountExistance' method, I return False and back in the initial method, if the return value is False 'sys.exit()' occurs.

The problem lies because I would rather not quit the program as its running a tkinter gui, allowing the user to change the registration details. Rather, is there a way of instead of quitting I can cancel the execution where it is and not submit duplicate values to a database.

To note, customerDetails() is called from another file upon the user pressing registration where stringVars() from entry boxes are fed into the class method. Also, the indentation appearance is not formatted properly on here but I have produced a minimal example for logic, and have cut out some lines of code.

```
class Database():
def __init__(self):
    Database.phoneNumber = ""

def accountExistance(email, phoneNumber):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    emailExist = cur.execute("SELECT count(email) FROM customerDetails WHERE email = ?", (email,)).fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    print(emailExist)
    phoneExist = cur.execute("SELECT count(phone) FROM customerDetails WHERE phone = ?", (phoneNumber,)).fetchall()
    print(phoneExist)
    conn.commit()
    if emailExist or phoneExist != 0 :
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Error", "This email and/or phone number is associated with an account")
        return False
        sys.exit()
    #else:
        #return True


#INSERT SIGN UP DETAILS
def customerDetails(forename, surname, dob, address, city,
    county, postcode, phone, email, password,verified, gender):

    print(forename, surname, dob, address, city, county, postcode,
          postcode, phone, email, password, verified, gender)

    test = Database.accountExistance(email, phone)
    if test == False:
        sys.exit()

    age = 0
    conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO customerDetails VALUES 
    (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(forename, surname, dob, address, city, 
    county, postcode, phone, email, password, verified, age, gender))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your condition to the following:

```
test = Database.accountExistance(email, phone)
if test == False:
    return # Stops the execution of the function
```

---

Also, if `test` is necessarily either `True` or `False`, you can check its value directly:

```
if not test:
```

is the same as

```
if test == False:
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Could you explain why return ends the execution? I did not know it has such capability. Regards

Comment: "The return statement causes your function to exit and hand back a value to its caller. The point of functions in general is to take in inputs and return something. The return statement is used when a function is ready to return a value to its caller."

Comment: You have a few `return` statements in your code. It just terminates the function with a value. A single `return` outputs `None`